# adding div to html code got with File_get_contents

Tags: php

I am using `file_get_contents` to get the html source of remote page, the code got consist of many tables.

what i am trying to do is the code has many `<td>` like the one below

```
   <td colspan="2">
         <b>Video </b> 
         <span class="section">Sports</span><b>: </b> 
         <span id="category466" class="category">Motor Sports</span>
    </td>
```

I want to add the div below just before closing `</td>`

```
<div style="float: right; padding-right: 2px;"><a class="open_event_tab" target="_blank" href="page123.html" >open event</a></div>
```

my code now look like this:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remotesite.com/page1.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
?>
```

and i am stopped at getElementsByTagName then i dont know waht to do to add the div as discriped above.

Comment: you can use regular expression to replace the <td></td>tag

Comment: @JasonYang can you please suggest code as i have no skill in regex

Answer (score 0):

This code works now with the updated HTML (below the code). It inserts the div at the places, where you want them do be.

```
<?php
//Get the url
$url = "http://remotesite.com/page1.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0'); // create DOMDocument
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$doc->loadXML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$filtered = $domxpath->query("//td[@colspan='2']");

$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
$length = $filtered->length;

$nodes = array();
for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    $node = $filtered->item($i);
    $lastChildHTML = $doc->saveXML($node->lastChild);
    if (strpos($lastChildHTML, 'class="category"') !== false) {
        $nodes[] = $node;
    }
}

$allTDNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
$tdNodes = array();
foreach ($allTDNodes as $tdNode) {
    if (in_array($tdNode, $nodes, true)) {
        $tdNodes[] = $tdNode;
    }
}
$tdNodes = array_reverse($tdNodes);

$length = count($nodes, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $replacement = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $nodeContent = $doc->saveXML($tdNodes[$i]);
    $replacement->appendXML($nodeContent);
    $divNode = createDivNode($doc);
    $replacement->firstChild->appendChild($divNode);
    $tdNodes[$i]->appendChild($divNode);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();

function createDivNode($doc) {
    $divNode = $doc->createElement('div');
    $divNode->setAttribute('style', 'float: right; padding-right: 2px;');
    $aNode = $doc->createElement('a', 'openEvent');
    $aNode->setAttribute('class', 'open_event_tab');
    $aNode->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    $aNode->setAttribute('href', 'page123.html');
    $divNode->appendChild($aNode);
    return $divNode;
}
```

I have [updated the used HTML](http://pastebin.com/hVnJH4bR) to make it XHTML compliant and fixed a style issue (the relevant areas had css property height: 0px attached to them).

Comment: I have found out why it didn't work. The foreach only works if you don't change something in the DOM. As DOM changes do happen, the for solution has to be taken. I have edited the answer for that.

Comment: sorry for that o think you are tired now but its not about the type also after correction it doesing work on more that one <td>

Comment: According to the comments on [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) I have updated the answer. It should now work.

Comment: here is the exact html i work on http://pastebin.com/KeaVDS3h also my full code is here http://pastebin.com/PgSwyQar

Comment: also note that i want to add this div to the <td> like the above not every <td> in the code

Comment: After a couple of hours of trying and testing with your HTML, I finally found a solution (look to answer). It does work with the updated HTML I posted.

Comment: thanks alot for your great effort to help me that very kind from you as you may notice my coding skills are very basic even your last answer giving error  Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: a line 22 and div in Entity, line: 22 in C:\xampp\htdocs\1.php on line 7 ( I offer you to work on my project as freelancer if you accept i can afford it)

Comment: I had tested the answer and it does work with the referenced HTML. As that is basically the HTML you use (that much I have to assume), it is the answer for your question. But I cannot provide you with a solution for whatever problem might occur in the future with a different HTML. The PHP code works for the (modified) HTML you have given.

Comment: but it seem that you have edited the html manully put in consideration that this ht,l is got from remote site how can i edit before echo it to my page

Comment: again please consider working on my website as freelancer i can afford you fees

Comment: @daleNale I won't work as a freelancer. I don't have time nor fun in doing other people's work. If I can help with a specific problem, I will on sites like SO. But I can't provide an ongoing support.

Comment: but it seem that you have edited the html manully put in consideration that this ht,l is got from remote site how can i edit before echo it to my page

Comment: Apparently the truth is coming only in small parts. As you posted the link to the HTML I had to assume that it was your HTML. How is anyone supposed to give an appropriate answer that fits your requirements, if you change the parameters every few comments or so.
Update the question with all the relevant stuff that you want an answer to. This is not thought to catch people that help you on an ongoing basis.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation!

The [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method returns an instance of [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

`DOMNodeList` implements the [`Traversible`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, which means that it can be used in a `foreach` loop. You can also loop over it using the [`DOMNodeList::$length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) property and the [`DOMNodeList::item($index)`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method.

Looping over the `DOMNodeList` you will be working with instances of [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). The `DOMNode` class has a method called [`DOMNode::appendChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php), which, funnily enough, takes a `DOMNode` as its argument.

Now you just have to create the `DOMNode` and append it. It may not be intuitive to work with the DOM, but at least it is *simple* once you get acquainted with the documentation.

Put [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) under your pillow.